# Can PostgreSQL databases be attached/detached on the fly?

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to attach/detach databases to PostgreSQL on the fly, i.e. while the server is running without having to restart the service? I can't find anything related to this in the documentation.

What I am trying to achieve is to have the user be able to select different data directories from an archive location and then have them loaded into PostgreSQL, and later removed when the user is finished.

Comment: Do you tried just create a new tablespace and move the database to a new place? Can you provide more details about your idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, short answer is no. This has been asked at the PostgreSQL development mailing list at 2011: [Detach/attach database](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAA-aLv5cQf09zvFRCB1XXUQLSp-ouX0S_Hq6ryScd6CtamipFQ@mail.gmail.com)
 and the many replies in summary said *"yes, this is feasible to implement but quite complicated to do so."*:

> You would have to do quite some surgery because of oids from shared tables. I don't think thats easily doable.
>
> Andres Freund
>
> ---
>
> The main reason this doesn't work is XID management.
>   It's barely possible you could make it work if you first locked all
>   other sessions out of the DB and then froze every XID in the database,
>   but that's a sufficiently heavyweight operation to make it of dubious
>   value.
>   ...
>
> Tom Lane
>
> ---
>
> I have to admit I've thought about this from time to time, and it
>   would be pretty cool.  I was initially thinking that it wouldn't be
>   that difficult to do this on a per-database level, because if you
>   slurp up a whole database then by definition you're also including the
>   system catalogs, which means that you have the pg_class, pg_attribute,
>   and pg_type entries that are necessary to interpret the table
>   contents.  If you do anything more fine-grained (per-tablespace,
>   per-table, or whatever) then things get much more complex, but at the
>   database level you only need to worry about interactions with other
>   globals: tablespace and role definitions.  And we could probably write
>   code to grovel through the system catalogs for a newly "mounted"
>   database and do search and replace on the appropriate columns, to map
>   from the old OIDs to the new ones.  It wouldn't be simple, but I think
>   it could be done.
>
> But Tom's point about XIDs and LSNs seems like it kind of puts a
>   bullet through the heart of the whole idea.  Now, before you can move
>   the database (or table, or whatever) between clusters, you've got to
>   rewrite all the data files to freeze XIDs and, I don't know, zero out
>   LSNs, or something.  And if you're going to rewrite all the data, then
>   you've pretty much lost all the benefit of doing this in the first
>   place. In fact, it might end up being *slower* than a dump and
>   restore; even an uncompressed dump will be smaller than the on-disk
>   footprint of the original database, and many dumps compress quite
>   well.
>
> Robert Haas
>
> ---
>
> What about having database-level XIDs rather than cluster-level?  Is that
>   remotely feasible?
>
> Thom Brown
>
> ---
>
> Maybe.  You'd need a set separate set for shared catalogs, too.  It
>   seems like a heck of a lot of work, though, especially since (IME,
>   anyway) most people only really one run one database per cluster.
>
> Robert Haas

Leaving aside all the internal implementation details / problems that would make this possible, the last comment has something that may be helpful to you:

Run a different cluster per database. You would probably need to implement 
something of an infrastructure so when a user wants to "attach" a database, it would start up the related cluster and stop it when the user wants to "detach" it.